# bash: displaying absolute path with symlinks resolved in prompt

Tags: linux, bash, ps1

Is it possible to have my shell display the full current working directory, even when I `cd` into a symlink? My current `PS1` reads

```
PS1="
[ \w ] 
=> "
```

However when I cd into a linked directory, it displays (for example) `[ ~/LINKEDDIR ]` instead of something more useful to me such as `[ /var/etc/bin/the/actual/path ]`.

Is there anyway to change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the `\w` escape sequence, you'll have to call the `pwd` utility directly and use its `-P` option to fully expand any symlinks. The following should work (note the single quotes, so that the command substitution is executed every time the prompt is displayed, rather than just once when `PS1` is defined).

```
PS1='\n[ $(pwd -P) ]\n=> '
```